# How to remove duplicate commands from irb history?

Tags: ruby, irb

I have searched several questions/answers/blogs without success. How to remove/delete duplicate commands from irb history?

Ideally I want to have the same behavior I configured for my bash. That is: after I execute a command every other entry in the history with the exactly same command is deleted.

But it would already be good to eliminate duplicates when I close irb.

My current `.irbrc`:

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 1000
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb_history"
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true
```

Note: Ruby 2.4.1 (or newer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will eliminate duplicates after closing IRB console. But it works only for IRBs using `Readline` (mac users warned).

```
# ~/.irbrc
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 1000
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb_history"

deduplicate_history = Proc.new do
    history = Readline::HISTORY.to_a
    Readline::HISTORY.clear
    history.reverse!.uniq!
    history.reverse!.each{|entry| Readline::HISTORY << entry}
end

IRB.conf[:AT_EXIT].unshift(deduplicate_history)
```

And this monkey patch will eliminate duplicates on the fly if your IRB is using `Readline`:

```
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 1000
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb_history"

class IRB::ReadlineInputMethod
    alias :default_gets :gets
    def gets
        if result = default_gets
            line = result.chomp
            history = HISTORY.to_a
            HISTORY.clear
            history.each{|entry| HISTORY << entry unless entry == line}
            HISTORY << line
        end
        result
    end
end
```

Any suggestion on how to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

An `AT_EXIT` hook is a perfectly acceptable way to do this. Though monkey patching is not needed. IRB provides facilities for doing this by creating your own input method.

IRB gets its input from an [`InputMethod`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB/InputMethod.html). History is provided by the 
[`ReadlineInputMethod`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB/ReadlineInputMethod.html), which is a subclass.

`InputMethod`s are attached to a [`Context`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB/Context.html). Entering `conf` in an `irb` session will give you access to the current context.

`irb` will read input according to the current context's `io`. For example:

```
irb [2.4.0] (screenstaring.com)$ conf.io
=> #<HistoryInputMethod:0x007fdc3403e180 @file_name="(line)", @line_no=3, @line=[nil, "4317.02 - 250 \n", "conf.id\n", "conf.io\n"], @eof=false, @stdin=#<IO:fd 0>, @stdout=#<IO:fd 1>, @prompt="irb [2.4.0] (screenstaring.com)$ ", @ignore_settings=[], @ignore_patterns=[]>
```

Uses [my Bash-like history control class](https://github.com/sshaw/dotfiles/blob/3e877d41578807b1da5f536e4714e1f07438958c/irbrc#L119-L147) (for more info see below).

You can set `conf.io` to anything that conforms to the `InputMethod` interface:

```
conf.io = MyInputMethod.new
```

Whatever `MyInputMethod#gets` returns will be evaluated by IRB. Typically it reads from `stdin`.

To tell IRB to use your `InputMethod` at startup you can set the `:SCRIPT` config option:

```
# .irbrc
IRB.conf[:SCRIPT] = MyInputMethod.new
```

IRB will use `:SCRIPT`'s value as input method when [creating a `Context`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB/Context.html#method-c-new). This can be set to a file to use its contents as the input method. 
By default it's `nil`, which results in `stdin` being used (via `Readline`, if it's available).

To create an input method that ignores duplicates override `ReadlineInputMethod#gets`:

```
class MyInputMethod < IRB::ReadlineInputMethod
  def gets
    line = super  # super adds line to HISTORY 
    HISTORY.pop if HISTORY[-1] == HISTORY[-2]
    line
  end
end
```

The `InputMethod` defined in [my `.irbrc`](https://github.com/sshaw/dotfiles/blob/3e877d41578807b1da5f536e4714e1f07438958c/irbrc#L119-L147) allows one to set `IRB_HISTCONTROL` or `IRB_HISTIGNORE` like you would (more or less) for Bash:

```
IRB_HISTIGNORE=ignoreboth IRB_HISTCONTROL='\Aq!:foo' irb
```

This does the following:

- Entries beginning with a space or duplicate (back-to-back) entries will not be added to the history
- Entries beginning with `q!` ([a custom method of mine](https://github.com/sshaw/dotfiles/blob/3e877d41578807b1da5f536e4714e1f07438958c/irbrc#L18)) or containing `foo` will not be added to history